# Google gmail script time auto reply

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Good morning,

Im looking to have an auto reply anytime someone emails me out of my normal office hours, M-F 8a-4p EST.

I've figured out how to do it on Sat & Sun, but can't figure out how to combine that with the time.  Below is what I'm using now.

Thank you for your help!

```
function autoReply() {
  var interval = 5;          //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
  var daysOff = [6,0];   // 1=Mo, 2=Tu, 3=We, 4=Th, 5=Fr, 6=Sa, 0=Su
  var message = "Thank you for your email! I am currently away from the office for the weekend spending time with my family. I will be back in the office Monday morning at 8:00 am EST.  My office hours are Monday - Friday 8:00 am - 4:00 pm EDT. I monitor email periodically over weekends for emergencies.  I look forward to assisting you when I am back in the office.  Thank you!"
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  if (daysOff.indexOf(day) > -1) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      threads[i].reply(message);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `getHours()`method in this way

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getHours();
if (n<8 || n>16){ 
      // "out of office";
}
else{
      //regular
}
```

Comment: var hour = date.getHours();
  if (wkend.indexOf(day) > -1 || (day == 5 && hour >= 16)) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      threads[i].reply(wkendMessage);
    }
  }
  else if (hour < 8 || hour >= 16) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      threads[i].reply(wkdayMessage);
    }
  }
}

Comment: Please explain what you mean

Comment: He instructed how to turn your code into a full answer. I upgraded it a bit and put it in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68088730/4829915

Answer (score 0):

I've combined the question's initial code with a modified version of [Eugene's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38955550/4829915):

```
    function autoReply() {
      var interval = 1;          //  if the script runs every X minutes
      var daysOff = [6,0];   // 1=Mo, 2=Tu, 3=We, 4=Th, 5=Fr, 6=Sa, 0=Su
      var workingHours = [9,17]; // 0-24
      var message = "Thank you for your email! \n\
      I am currently OOO and will be back in regular office hours (though I monitor email periodically for emergencies). \n\Looking forward to assisting you when I am back in the office. Thank you for your understanding!"
      var date = new Date();
      var day = date.getDay();
      var hour = date.getHours();
      if (daysOff.indexOf(day) > -1 || n<workingHours[0] || n>workingHours[1]) {
        var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
        var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
        for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
          threads[i].reply(message);
      }
    }
```